# How to attribute URI to a primitive of an ontology using jena?

Tags: uri, jena, ontology, primitive

I have retrieved all primitives of my ontology using Jena. And now, I have to make URI for each primitive which has no URI (like blank node and literals) but I don't know how to proceed. If someone can help please.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do?  It's not difficult to generate random URIs, right?  (E.g., you could just do `<urn:ex:[random-string]>`.  Are you asking how you'd update the ontology to "replace" the blank node with the URI?  And note that while you could always replace a blank node with a URI, you can't necessarily replace a literal with a URI and preserve the meaning.

Comment: Yes, but do note that the things in, e.g., an OWL ontology, that are blank nodes don't often need a name;  they're anonymous for a reason.  And literals represent literal data (like a string, or a number).  You can replace `<http://.../Jack> <http://.../hasAge> 23` with `<http://.../Jack> <http://.../hasAge> <http://.../numbers/23>`, but somewhere, you're still going to want to know that `<http://.../numbers/23>` is somehow related to the actual value `23`.